# C program compiles without errors but will not run and gives no warnings or errors

Tags: c, gcc, sdl, sdl-2

**TL;DR** Program works on one system. On home system it hangs before reaching the main entry point (checked with debugger).

---

I have a local repository of code for a group project, synced up to the latest version that I have tested on several other machines (including Linux, Windows and Macs) that I am sure will work without giving any nasty errors. It's a fairly straightforward program, the main technical challenge we've dealt with has been linking in SDL2, which has been fairly easy.

The program compiles perfectly on my local machine and throws no warnings or errors even with as many of the warning flags turned on as possible. I've made sure that I'm not accidentally using .o files from a different system and I've cleaned then recompiled the code several times. I've reverted my local repository back to older code from the project that I'm also sure previously compiled and ran on my local machine.

I've made sure that the linking in of external libraries in gcc is working correctly, and there are no warnings or errors coming from that. The final linking together of the .o files is also error and warning free.

I've re-installed all the relevant .DLLs (in this case, the only DLL is the SDL one) for the program I'm working, both in the logical system locations and the working directory of the compiled executables. I've made sure that the .DLLs are the correct bit versions, and even tried the wrong bit versions in case I was accidentally making a version that needed the other bit versions.

I've re-installed my compiler (which I'm getting from Msys2 at the moment), and I've tried using the compiler that comes from Mingw64 instead.

None of these things have made any difference. When I go to run the executable, nothing will happen. No process is created and any terminal window which I'm running it from will just hang until I force close it (it won't respond to ctrl-c).

If I try running it in debug mode, gdb will be able to open the executable, and give me all the information, but once I try to run it, it will hang just like the terminal windows. Even if I try to break it at the entry point, the program seems to never get to the entry point, because it still hangs.

This problem started completely randomly. I came home from my university, having been working on the code before I went to university that day and having left it in a compilable state, came home, hit make and it wouldn't run. This was even before I had pulled the changes that we had committed and pushed that day, which is why I'm completely lost as to exactly why this will compile so happily yet absolutely refuse to run in any conditions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. This will help the Stack Overflow community by clarifying the problem.

Comment: Maybe it's your environment, not your particular code.  If you build a simple "Hello, World!" program, does it run for you?

Comment: of intererest: [Is there any way a C/C++ program can crash before main()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518415/is-there-any-way-a-c-c-program-can-crash-before-main)

Answer (score 1):

If the debugger doesn't reach the main entry point, then the most likely culprit I can think of is [static initialization fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order), which is consistent with the behavior you describe: works on one system, fails on another.

Without seeing any code, we are just throwing arrows in the dark.

C vs C++:

Static initialization fiasco applies to C++ only, but keep in mind that libraries, even libraries linked to a C program can contain C++ code (not necessarily exposed as an interface).

Be sure to check [Is there any way a C/C++ program can crash before main()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518415/is-there-any-way-a-c-c-program-can-crash-before-main) .

@JohnBollinger had an excellent comment: check if a simple program (compiled with the same compiler & flags) runs. We sometime get absorbed on where we think the problem is, that we can easily miss things like this.

Another thing you can do is to use `ldd` to see if the correct libraries are linked to your program.

Comment: That's a c++ problem though...

Comment: @EOF didn't read the `C` tag.... will delete answer....

Comment: Well, maybe the tags are incorrect..

Comment: also the libraries linked can contain c++ object code