# I have an c++ code which crashes on startup before reaching execution of main() where might the issue reside?

Tags: c++

I am bachelor student, I was asked this question by my instructor could you pls help me in this.
I already did googling about it but I am still confused.

Is there any tool who find out the reason of crashes?

I will really appreciate your time.

Comment: yes - its called a debugger. What platform are you on

Comment: Some code please. Alternatively, you can also DEBUG and find it out yourself.

Comment: @Ajay it was kind of an interview question, basically asking for a code example that can crash before main starts

Comment: One common cause iin Windows is that a required DLL is not found.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518415/is-there-any-way-a-c-c-program-can-crash-before-main

Comment: Hi, guys it was an interview question and I did not able to answer. Yes, I replied debugging but they did not impressed with this answer. @Ajay

Comment: `int foo() { return *((int*)0); } int global = foo(); int main(){}`

Comment: thank you @pm100. appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that take place before the actual execution starts. The first thing that comes to my mind is initialization of global variables. For example:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int getSomeValue(){
    // some code to produce crash, e.g. as suggested by Barmar...
    abort();
    return 0;
}

int value = getSomeValue();

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

And concerning your question of how to find such a bug, the answer is: use a debugger.

Comment: just to be clear - this code does NOT crash before main

Comment: actually I wasnt sure...

Comment: @pm100 but arent global variables initialized before main starts?

Comment: `getSomeValue` has to cause crash. Global variables are initialized before `main`. `static` (function level) variables get initialized on their first usage

Comment: @Ajay so you agree that my example crashes before main?

Comment: why would it crash? You need to replace the comment by some bad code

Comment: @pm100 well, if that is your problem... I just didnt want to make it too specific. I mean there are several ways to cause a crash, but only if a function causing a crash is used to initialize a global variable this happens before main and thats what I wanted to illustrate. Anyhow I will make it more explicit

Comment: To be pedantic, this causes undefined behavior. Whether it actually causes a crash is implementation-dependent. But that's more a fault of the way the question was asked.

Comment: @Barmar and for this reason I previously I didnt provide any code that does cause the crash, but only the comment that was supposed to be replcaced with some crash causing code. Usually I avoid crashing my programs, thus I have little experience how to do it ;). Arent in fact all crashs implementation dependent ?

Comment: I suppose you could call `abort()`, that's supposed to crash the program.

Comment: @Barmar ah thanks, thats a good example of something that one actually would use in real code. Well, not in this way, but still better than some lousy UB

Answer (score 0):

As @tobi303 said, global variables get initialized before `main`.

If one of those global variables is an object, then that object's Constructor gets run before `main`.

If that Constructor calls other functions, then those functions are also called before `main`.

```
class SelfCrashing
{
public:
    SelfCrashing() { int x = *(int*)NULL; } // Deliberate crash
};

SelfCrashing myGlobal; // Default Constructor called

int main()
{
    /* Program never got here */
}
```